# Having a thread using Hibernate and C3p0 with database on Tomcat

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, c3p0

I am using Hibernate and C3P0 to manage my connections. 
I also have a thread to do database operations.

The problem is when I undeploy my webapp from tomcat, my thread exits correctly, but the connection pool still remains, there are still connections in mysql, I think they are managed by C3P0.

Is there a way to force C3P0 to shutdown all these connections?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [PooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html) object, it has a method called `hardReset`. It's spec says

> Destroys all pooled and checked-out Connections associated with this DataSource immediately. The PooledDataSource is reset to its initial state prior to first Connection acquisition, with no pools yet active, but ready for requests.

I would assume this should do what you are asking for.